# Devo me preocupar em obter todas as medalhas?

Tags: debate, medalhas

Existem diversas medalhas que podem ser obtidas no site, sendo que no meu entendimento, elas tem o propósito de aumentar a qualidade do conteúdo disponível no site.

Partindo deste principio, algumas medalhas me parecem bastante suspeitas, como a medalha **Assistente de Pesquisa**.

> Editar wikis de 50 tags

Obviamente ajudar a manter a qualidade do conteúdo do site é importante, mas considerando que temos poucas tags novas por dia, não vejo motivo para ficar editando as tags que já estão consolidadas.

Vale a pena tentar ganhar este tipo de medalha?

O seu mérito me parece um pouco vazio, pois se vamos editar apenas por editar, não iremos adicionar nada ao site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As medalhas servem como forma de mostrar pra pessoa que é interessante ela fazer determinada tarefa em um primeiro momento e depois ainda dar um "empurrãozinho" depois que a pessoa começa para continuar, pra ela saber que "ganha alguma coisa" fazendo. É muito fácil a pessoa esquecer, desistir se não tiver um incentivo.

Todas medalhas foram criadas para incentivar bons comportamentos. Claro que é possível abusar em algumas.

Se a pessoa abusar demais o sistema e/ou os moderadores podem tirar o privilégio da pessoa que está fazendo a atividade sem muito critério só para ganhar medalha.

Claro que está longe de ser necessário ganhar todas medalhas, inclusive é quase impossível obter todas mesmo. Deve fazer organicamente. Use-as para isto que eu disse, identificar o que a comunidade valoriza que você faça e como incentivo para continuar fazendo um bom trabalho.

Tem bastante wiki de *tag* que se beneficiaria se tiver uma boa descrição, pelo menos no resumo, falando sobre o que é o assunto de forma bem simples e como e quando usar a *tag*, que é uma das coisas mais importantes.

Answer (score 7):

> [...]não vejo motivo para ficar editando as tags que já estão
>   consolidadas.[...]

A edição não é da *TAG*, mas sim do *Wiki* da *TAG*. E importante manter as wikis atualizadas porque tudo muda com um passar do tempo, e na tecnologia não é nada diferente.

Um tempo atrás editei a tag [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) adicionando o Xamarin, que é uma plataforma de desenvolvimento de aplicativos móveis nativos, incluindo Android, iOS e Windows Phone. Pois então, as vezes as pessoas podem entrar para saber mais sobre a *TAG* e supostamente agrega mais ao conhecimento.

De fato, na teoria, deve haver todo um estudo e pesquisa para criação de uma nova medalha. Isso inclui a questão do peso e dificuldade para obtenção desta mesma.

> Vale a pena tentar ganhar este tipo de medalha?

Vai do seu próprio critério, o que julgar importante para sua coleção de medalhas, considerando que ninguém é obrigado a nada dentro da comunidade. Tudo aqui é colaboração e o primeiro pensamento que deveria vir é a questão de ajudar, e não no que vai receber ajudando. No mundo real é assim também, muitas vezes agimos por interesse, por saber que iremos receber algo em troca, como a  Lei da Colheita: "Você colhe o que você planta".

A intenção da edição, obviamente não deveria ser "editar apenas por editar" e sim para melhoria do conteúdo da comunidade. Acredito que ter essa medalha também seja importante, justamente para manter as *wikis* atualizadas.